# Timesheet recording in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

My old company had quarter hour requirements. 7 hours and 10 minutes would be 7 hours 15 minutes and I entered into my timecard as `7.25`.

My new company does it by 6 minute intervals eg., `0.1 equals 6 minutes, 0.2 equals 12 minutes` I used to use the code below to round to the quarter hour which I found online.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E21)," ", ROUND((G21*24)/0.25,0)*0.25)
```

How do I change it to do the `0.1, 0.2` and so forth requirements?

Edited to include my complete timesheet and formulas

```
A2   B2    C2    D2    E2   F2   G2   H2
6:50 12:15 12:45 16:00 8:40 8:45 8.75 8.8
```

Formulas in their respective cells

```
E2 =IF(ISBLANK($D2)," ",(B2<A2)+B2-A2+(D2<C2)+D2-C2)
F2 =IF(ISBLANK($D2)," ", TIME(HOUR(E2), ROUND((MINUTE(E2)/60)*4, 0) * 15, 0))
G2 =IF(ISBLANK(D2)," ", ROUND((F2*24)/0.25,0)*0.25)
H2 =IF(ISBLANK(D2)," ", ROUND((F2*24)/0.1,0)*0.1)

E2 is the total number of hours worked
F2 is the number of quarter hours worked
G2 is the number of quarter hours for a different time reporting system (requires .25/.50/.75)
H2 is the number in decimal format for current timesheet.
```

From my understanding I will need to change F2 to split 6 minutes in half?

Comment: Can you give an example? What is in G21

Comment: Swap out 0.25 for 0.1  ...

Comment: @jeremyA1, what if 7 hours and 2 minutes? 7hr and 3min?

Comment: Though you have accepted the answer, please have a look at the alternative formula and provide your valuable feedback.

Comment: I updated my original post to include everything I'm using. I believe you're correct about the 7hrs. and 3 mins. example. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula

`=IF(ISBLANK(E21)," ", ROUND((G21*24)/0.1,0)*0.1)`

Answer (score 0):

If working with 10^x'th round, you can directly use:

```
=IF(LEN(E21),ROUND(G21*24,1),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative formula for same requirement.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E21)," ",(INT(G21)+INT(((G21-TRUNC(G21))*100)/6)/10))
```

[image: Snapshot of results]